# Usage of participle with and without comma

Tags: punctuation

Arguing with my friend, we've both got stuck on the one question about participles, the meaning of which confused us.

> I don't like myself being beaten

Does that mean I don't like it when I'm getting beaten?

> I don't like myself, being beaten

Does that mean I don't like myself when I'm getting beaten?

It makes sense to me, however, everyone can be mistaken. I'm a little familiar with English punctuation. By this question, I'm testing myself. I wouldn't mind knowing whether I am right or not.

I appreciate any help. Besides, sorry for my mistakes if there're some in this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you to be writing about beaten in the context of a competition rather than an assault.

The first sentence implies a general statement based on previous experience that, if and when you are beaten, you do not like it. It does not imply that you have actually been beaten within the context of the sentence.

The second sentence with its comma puts “being beaten” in apposition to “myself”, suggesting that you have actually been beaten within the context of the sentence and that you do not like that particular circumstance.